# Filter dataframe list values contained in dataframe cells

Tags: python, pandas, list, filter

I have a dataframe, products` with a column that contains semicolon-separated lists of tags like so

```
Tags
________________
tag1;tag2;tag4
tag3;tag1
tag4;tag2;tag6
...etc
```

I would like to filter `products` on whether `Tag2` is contained in the tags list.

I've tried the following:

```
products["Tag2" in products["Tags"].str.split(";", expand=True)]
```

But receive `KeyError: False`

Any tips would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `df.Tags.str.contains('tag2')` ?

Comment: @harvpan That serves the purpose provided that the tag I'm searching isn't a substring of a tag that I'm not searching for.  For example the above would return rows containing tag2 AND tag 22.

Comment: checkout the answer.

Comment: `product['Tags'].str.split(';',exand=True).eq('tag2').any(1)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
products[products['tags'].apply(lambda x: 'tag2' in x.split(';'))]
```

Answer (score 1):

A **better (smarter)** way is to use **[get_dummies](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html)**:

```
df.loc[df['Tags'].str.get_dummies(';')['tag2'].eq(1)]
```

Output:

```
              Tags
0   tag1;tag2;tag4
```

Her is a better example to cover all cases:

**Data**:

```
    Tags
0   tag1;tag2;tag4
1   tag3;tag1
2   tag4;tag22;tag6
3   tag2
```

**Code**:

```
df.loc[df['Tags'].str.get_dummies(';')['tag2'].eq(1)]
```

**Output**:

```
              Tags
0   tag1;tag2;tag4
3   tag2
```

You can alternatively use:

You need to look for substring `tag2;` so that exact match is performed.

```
df.loc[(df.Tags+';').str.contains('tag2;')]
```

Comment: Also thought of this but @QuangHoang is quite right; I do appreciate the effort however

Comment: @QuangHoang good point, I thought tags are ended with `;` edit coming soon.

Comment: lemme guess `(df['Tags'] +';')` :-)

Comment: @QuangHoang not above using that hack if I get desperate ;-)

Comment: @harvpan It works, provided that tag2 is actually present in the dataset. Unfortunately this errors out with a `KeyError: tag2` if tag2 is not present in the dataset.  I would need it to return no rows instead.

Comment: @neanderslob in that case, second solution would work. Also, you can handle the keyerror. My solution is way faster than the accepted solution. `apply+lambda` is always slower.

Answer (score 0):

*Tags* column in your DataFrame contains actually **strings**.

So, instead of converting these strings into lists, just check
whether each string contains *tag2*:

```
product[product.Tags.str.contains('tag2')]
```

The result (for your data) is:

```
             Tags
0  tag1;tag2;tag4
2  tag4;tag2;tag6
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it wouldn't work for  a circumstance where tag2 was at the end of the list.  ...I could append a semicolon to the values but it seems hacky

Comment: I checked for *tag1;tag4;tag2* as the first row and it **does** appear in the output. Quite natural, since the first row still contains *tag2* (of course, at the end, but this doesn't matter).